# Get property value Sharepoint Property bag for web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api, sharepoint, csom

I created a MVC web api that querys a list on sharepoint, this will run in different enviroments. I need to have a property on the property bag for each one so I can access it from my web Api, how can I call the property value from here? I'm using CSOM.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get the value of a PropertyBag property via CSOM. There are multiple PropertyBags in SharePoint, the farm, a webapplication, a site collection and a website do all have their own PropertyBag.

You could get the value of a property in a website's PropertyBag like this:

```
clientContext.Load(web, w => w.AllProperties);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

if (!web.AllProperties.FieldValues.ContainsKey(propertyName))
{
    // property with this name does not exist
    return null;
}
else
{
    // return (object) value of property
    return web.AllProperties[propertyName];
}
```